plotly rendered dashboard callbacks not instantiated correctly
We have a Dash application with a login page that authenticates users using Flask-Login. Once authenticated, the application dynamically loads a dashboard module, which in this case is a test module named modal_test.
The test module is supposed to display a button that opens a modal when clicked, and it includes callbacks to handle this interaction.
ComponentsLogin Page (app.py):Displays a login form where users can enter their username and password.Upon successful login, it dynamically loads the modal_test dashboard module and sets up its callbacks.
**Dashboard Module (modal_test.py):**Contains a layout with a button that should open a modal when clicked.Includes callback functions to handle the opening and closing of the modal.
Problem
The issue is that while the callbacks in the modal_test module are registered (as indicated by the "Registering callbacks..." debug print), the functions within these callbacks are not being executed when the button is clicked. This means the modal does not open as expected, and no related debug statements are printed to the console.
What We're Trying to Solve
Callback Registration Verification:Ensure that the callbacks in modal_test.py are correctly registered when the module is loaded.Verify that the setup_callbacks function is called after setting the layout.Callback
Triggering:Understand why the callback functions (e.g., toggle_modal) are not being triggered when the button is clicked.Ensure that the input IDs used in the callback definitions match those in the layout.
app.py
This script includes the login page and the logic to load the modal_test module upon successful login.
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import html, dcc, Input, Output, State, ctx
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_user, UserMixin, current_user
import os
import secrets
import importlib
from functools import lru_cache
import json

# Flask server setup
server = Flask(__name__)
server.secret_key = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY', secrets.token_urlsafe(16))
app = dash.Dash(__name__, server=server, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP], suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

# Flask-Login setup
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(server)

# Dummy user class for authentication
class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

# In-memory user store
users = {'testuser': 'testpassword'}

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User(user_id)

# Login page layout
login_color = '#06bfa9'
login_layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        html.H2("Welcome to the App", style={'color': login_color, 'textAlign': 'center'}),
        dcc.Input(id='username', type='text', placeholder='Username', 
                  style={'backgroundColor': '#1a1a1a', 'color': login_color, 'border': 'none', 'borderRadius': '5px', 'padding': '10px', 'margin': '10px 0', 'width': '100%'}),
        dcc.Input(id='password', type='password', placeholder='Password', 
                  style={'backgroundColor': '#1a1a1a', 'color': login_color, 'border': 'none', 'borderRadius': '5px', 'padding': '10px', 'margin': '10px 0', 'width': '100%'}),
        dbc.Button('Login', id='login-button', 
                   style={'backgroundColor': login_color, 'color': '#1a1a1a', 'border': 'none', 'borderRadius': '5px', 'padding': '10px', 'width': '100%', 'cursor': 'pointer'}),
    ], style={'width': '300px', 'padding': '20px', 'border': '2px solid #00E5FF', 'borderRadius': '10px', 'backgroundColor': '#2c2c2c'}),
], style={'display': 'flex', 'justifyContent': 'center', 'alignItems': 'center', 'height': '100vh', 'backgroundColor': '#1a1a1a'})

# Main layout
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=True),
    html.Div(id='page-content', children=login_layout),
    html.Div(id='dashboard-content')  # Placeholder for the selected dashboard content
])

# Login callback
@app.callback(
    [Output('page-content', 'children'),
     Output('dashboard-content', 'children')],
    [Input('login-button', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('username', 'value'), State('password', 'value')],
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def login(n_clicks, username, password):
    if username in users and users[username] == password:
        user = User(username)
        login_user(user)
        dashboard_module = load_dashboard_module('modal_test')
        if dashboard_module:
            layout = dashboard_module.create_layout(app)
            if hasattr(dashboard_module, 'setup_callbacks'):
                dashboard_module.setup_callbacks(app)
            return html.Div(), layout
    return login_layout, html.Div('Login failed. Please try again.')

@lru_cache(maxsize=32)
def load_dashboard_module(script_name):
    """Dynamically import and cache dashboard modules."""
    try:
        module = importlib.import_module(f"dashes.{script_name}")
        if hasattr(module, 'create_layout') and callable(module.create_layout):
            print(f"Successfully loaded module: {script_name}")
            return module
        else:
            print(f"Module {script_name} does not have a callable 'create_layout' function")
    except ImportError as e:
        print(f"ImportError for module {script_name}: {e}")
    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host="0.0.0.0", port=8050, debug=True)

modal_test.py
This script defines a simple dashboard module with a button to open a modal and includes callbacks to handle the button clicks.
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import html, Input, Output, State, callback_context

def create_layout(app):
    return dbc.Container(
        [
            dbc.Button("Open Modal", id="open-modal-button", n_clicks=0),
            dbc.Modal(
                [
                    dbc.ModalHeader(dbc.ModalTitle("Modal Header")),
                    dbc.ModalBody("This is the content of the modal"),
                    dbc.ModalFooter(
                        dbc.Button("Close", id="close-modal-button", className="ml-auto")
                    ),
                ],
                id="example-modal",
                is_open=False,
            ),
            html.Div(id="output-div")  # For testing callback
        ],
        fluid=True,
        className="p-5",
    )

def setup_callbacks(app):
    print("Registering callbacks...")

    @app.callback(
        Output("example-modal", "is_open"),
        [Input("open-modal-button", "n_clicks"), Input("close-modal-button", "n_clicks")],
        [State("example-modal", "is_open")],
    )
    def toggle_modal(n1, n2, is_open):
        print("toggle_modal called")
        print(f"n1: {n1}, n2: {n2}, is_open: {is_open}")
        print("Callback context:", callback_context.triggered)
        if n1 or n2:
            return not is_open
        return is_open

    @app.callback(
        Output("output-div", "children"),
        [Input("open-modal-button", "n_clicks")],
    )
    def test_button_click(n_clicks):
        print("test_button_click called")
        print(f"Button clicked {n_clicks} times")
        print("Button click context:", callback_context.triggered)
        return f"Button clicked {n_clicks} times"`

Summary
I am facing an issue where callbacks within the modal_test dashboard module are not being triggered when the button is clicked, even though they are registered. The goal is to understand why the callbacks are not being executed and to find a solution to ensure they work as expected. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
actually tried multiple logging and troubleshooting steps.

In app.py, you need to register all callbacks - ie. including those from the dashboard module(s) - before calling app.run(), which means you can't load those modules dynamically from within a callback, just do :
from modal_test import create_layout, setup_callbacks

And for the callbacks (after app.layout = html.Div([])) :
# Dashboard module callbacks
setup_callbacks(app)

# Login callback
@app.callback(
    [Output('page-content', 'children'),
     Output('dashboard-content', 'children')],
    [Input('login-button', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('username', 'value'), State('password', 'value')],
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def login(n_clicks, username, password):
    if username in users and users[username] == password:
        user = User(username)
        login_user(user)
        modal_layout = create_layout(app)
        return html.Div(), modal_layout
    return login_layout, html.Div('Login failed. Please try again.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host="0.0.0.0", port=8050, debug=True)

Another approach would be to build a Multi-Page App
